# onPhyUpdate is triggered with status 6 = GATT_REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I'm developing an Android app which communicates via BLE with an external module, and I am trying to set the BLE connection PHY.
I've tried calling the method `gatt.setPreferredPhy(txPhy, rxPhy, phyOptions)` with all the different phy type integer arguments (for both tx and rx), and added the appropriate integer argument for phyOptions in case I was requesting a coded phy.

Every time the onPhyUpdate callback is invoked with a status 6 = GATT_REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED.

All other GATT callbacks are invoked with a status 0 = GATT_SUCCESS.

My permissions:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> ```

The Android device spec, according to nrf connect:[image]

The datasheet for the bluetooth module I'm communicating with:

https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/da14531-datasheet?language=en&r=1564826

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error says that your peripheral (the Renesas) doesn't support this particular GATT request. I quickly scanned the Renesas doc and I couldn't find any confirmation that it support 2M phy....